# php file_get_contents() str_replace &nbsp; with ""

Tags: php, function, str-replace

I am having problem with Google's Currency api. Data I am receiving contains:

`{lhs: "1000 Euros",rhs: "111 844.933 Serbian dinars",error: "",icc: true}`

where "111 844.933" is actually "111**& nbsp;**844.933".

However, I cannot find a way to replace "**& nbsp;**" with empty string so my string would be "111844.933"

Comment: You sure? It's certainly not `&nbsp;` (an HTML entitiy), at most it's a Unicode non-breaking space character. But the data you pasted just contains a normal space.

Comment: I am 100% sure since I tried to output it and when you look at the page's source, you will see & nbsp; or � character sometimes

Comment: I tried to replace � character too (yes, that one with ? in box) but php doesn't replace it as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can do this:

```
echo str_replace('&nbsp;', '', '{lhs: "1000 Euros",rhs: "111&nbsp;844.933 Serbian dinars",error: "",icc: true}');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zzrhDn)

Comment: Then it is not an `&nbsp;` that you're seeing there

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RJJ3Lf I have exploded result by " " and you will see how array is structured. if you inspect page source, you will see 111&nbsp;xxx.xx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php).

Try this code :

```
<?php
    $string = '{lhs: "1000 Euros",rhs: "111 844.933 Serbian dinars",error: "",icc: true}';
    $find = array("&nbsp"); 
    $replace = array("");
    $string = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
    echo $string;
?>
```